# file_exists never returns false in if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, file-exists

Everything works, but the `else` statement won't run.

```
<?php
$localhost  = "http://localhost";
/* $target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploadmod/uploads/'; 
 */

$target_dir = "uploads/";

if ($handle = opendir("$target_dir")) {

    while (false !== ($file_name = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file_name != "." && $file_name != "..") {
            preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $file_name);

            if (file_exists($target_dir.$file_name)) {
                echo "<img src=$target_dir". $file_name. ' ' . 'width=25%' . ' ' . 'height='."><br />";
                echo "<a href=$localhost/uploadmod/image.php?cmd=viewimage&file_name=$file_name".">View this image</a><br />";
                echo "<a href=$localhost/uploadmod/delete_image.php?cmd=delete&file_name=$file_name".">delete</a><br /><br />";
            } else {
                echo "no image found";
            }
        }

    }
    closedir($handle);
} 

?>
```

Comment: Just making sure - You ran your code with the `$target_dir` un-commented right?

Comment: so in your else condition you are just going to display message `"no image found"` and it don't display even the file doesn't exist

Comment: yes, i ran it uncommented, it was a blank page, not sure why, but the other way works. when there are no images the "no image found" wont display.

Comment: Randy, I think you need to understand your code first. If there are no files in the directory, your code will never enter in while loop, so it will never display `no image found`. Read more about  `opendir` and `readdir`. In short, your while loop will always have a file. Its `readdir`'s job to read the directory.

Comment: Thank you, i'm just a noob, I'll do more reading here, thanks all.